# I need to get an output like below from a single SQL query to dual table. How to do it?

Tags: sql, oracle

Example : My query output should be something like this below

```
1   L   R

--  --  --

1   1   1 
1   1   2 
1   1   3 
1   2   1 
1   2   2 
1   2   3  
1   3   1 
1   3   2 
1   3   3
```

Comment: so... populate a table like you've shown, and `select * from my_table`? You need to give way more context on what the issue is, and what you've tried already.

Comment: Is this a puzzle of some sort? If so, just asking for an answer is completely and utterly pointless. If not, what is the *real* problem you're having that made you think this would be a good way to solve it?

Comment: Looks like counting in a base-3 system with characters 1, 2, 3 in stead of 0, 1, 2. You could look into some variable-base counting/calculating algorithms? Or if 1 of these columns is existing input, look at things like `RANK()`, `DENSE_RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: @hvd Yes, It was asked in an interview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you realise that what you're trying to do is a cartesian product of `{1, 2, 3}` with itself (twice), it is not very hard to do.

Something like:

```
with nums as (
    select rownum num from dual connect by level <= 2
)   
select 1, a.num as l, b.num as r
from nums a, nums b;
```

Now all you have to do is extend this to three values instead of two.